# Cannot autowire service

Tags: symfony5

No se porque en el foro ingles me han baneado por realizar esta consulta, sin darme la posibilidad de editarla o o publicar otra pregunta, estoy alucinando. Ojo no me molesta porque me digan que la pregunta no esta bien planteada, sino por el hecho de no darme la posibilidad de corregirla y eso que la borre. En fin ya he soltado mi pataleta voy a la cuestión en si.

He creado una clase Usuarios y su repositorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y obtengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando por internet he encontrado que es porque esta activado el autowire y daban como una posible solución el usar ServiceEntityRepository en lugar de EntityRepository pero eso creo que es en Symfony 4, yo uso Symfony 5 y no se si la configración es diferente.

Mi services.yaml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A ver si alguien me puede guiar con este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la solución aquí --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024235/cannot-autowire-service-argument-references-class-but-no-such-service-exists

Era lo que había leido pero no lo estaba aplicando bien

Usar ServiceEntityRepository

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y añadir el constructor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]